# Jupyter Notebook: editing files outside of /home and/or hidden ones - workarounds

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

What workarounds do you use in classic Jupyter Notebook (not Lab) to edit files outside of the user home folder (`~/`) and/or files in hidden subfolders (e.g. in `~/.config`)?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've been using involves using Jupyter's Terminal and bash commands (`cd`) or Midnight Commander (`mc`) for browsing into hidden folders (including those outside of the `/home` folder) and terminal-based editors like `nano` or `vim` for editing the hidden files (the latter has better support for YAML, but the former is more intuitive):

```
sudo apt install -y mc nano vim
```